# Ensure output grammatically correct too pedantic?

Tags: bash, coding-style, standards

Say I have a bash script which calculates the number of indices and tables being used, and displays it to a user. The most straightforward output would obviously be

```
echo ${numIndices} Indices
echo ${numTables} Tables
```

but for certain cases the output would be grammatically incorrect, e.g. 1 Index and 1 Table would output as

```
1 Indices
1 Tables
```

so a solution to cover all cases would be

```
if [[ ${numIndices} -eq 0 && ${numTables} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Tables
elif [[ ${numIndices} -eq 0 && ${numTables} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Table
elif [[ ${numIndices} -eq 0 && ${numTables} -gt 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Tables
elif [[ ${numIndices} -eq 1 && ${numTables} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Index
    echo ${numTables} Tables
elif [[ ${numIndices} -eq 1 && ${numTables} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Index
    echo ${numTables} Table
elif [[ ${numIndices} -eq 1 && ${numTables} -gt 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Index
    echo ${numTables} Tables
elif [[ ${numIndices} -gt 1 && ${numTables} -eq 0 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Table
elif [[ ${numIndices} -gt 1 && ${numTables} -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Table
elif [[ ${numIndices} -gt 1 && ${numTables} -gt 1 ]]; then
    echo ${numIndices} Indices
    echo ${numTables} Tables
fi
```

Would something like this be considered too pedantic/inefficient/unreadable and generally frowned upon in programming?

Comment: Split the two output lines up and you only need one `if` for each instead of that mess.

Comment: As with all things in programming, it depends. If your target users are english professors, then have at it;-) Otherwise, a dual text like `(Index|Indices)` , but really, in the general programming world, life it too short. Spend your time on interesting problems! ;-) Finally, you could reduce the complexity by testing `${numIndices}` in one block, and `${numTables}` in a separate block.

Comment: It comes across as more acceptable, to me at least, if you do `Indices: 1`, `Tables: 1` rather than `1 Indices` and `1 Tables`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Write a function:

```
plural(){
    if [[ $1 -eq 1 ]]
    then
        echo "$1 $2"
    else
        echo "$1 $3"
    fi
}
```

Then you can just do this:

```
plural "${numIndices}" Index Indices
plural "${numTables}" Table Tables
```

Answer (score 3):

It also depends on localization needs. If your code needs to support output in many languages (now, or eventually), hard-coding rules for English is a waste if effort, not least because the rules for many other languages are going to be orders of magnitude more complex.

Comment: Recommended reading: [Locale::Maketext::TPJ13](http://search.cpan.org/~jhi/perl-5.8.1/lib/Locale/Maketext/TPJ13.pod) -- it's about a Perl module, but most if it is general interest.

Answer (score 2):

You just need better implementation, something like this:

```
echo_count(){
  if [ "$1" = 1 ]; then
    echo $1 $2
  else
    echo $1 $3
  fi
}
echo_count 1 Index Indices
echo_count 2 Table Tables
```

output

```
1 Index
2 Tables
```

Answer (score 2):

"Indexes" is an acceptable plural of index if you aren't writing Latin text. I wouldn't worry about  using the exact right form and simply output

```
1 Table(s)
1 Index(es)
```

If you do want to be pedantic, treat each case separately. Your `if` statement has a lot of redundant cases.

```
if [[ $numTables -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "1 Table"
else
    echo "$numTables Tables"
fi
if [[ $numIndices -eq 1 ]]; then
    echo "1 Index"
else
    echo "$numTables Indices"
fi
```

or some oneliners

```
[[ $numTables -eq 1 ]] && echo "1 Table" || echo "$numTables Tables"
[[ $numIndices eq 1 ]] && echo "1 Index" || echo "$numIndices Indices"
```